# How do I get Ubuntu MATE to open .jar files with java and .zip files with Engrampa?

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu-mate

I'm having a bit of an issue with not being able to have .jar files open in Java, and .zip files open in Engrampa at the same time. It seems that Ubuntu MATE thinks that .jar files and .zip files are the same type of file. I know that they technically are, in that both are zip files, but a .jar is a java program, not a data file(which is what a .zip is).

How do I convince Ubuntu that they are, in fact, different file types?
EDIT: I just realised this isn't all that clear as to what I'm trying to achieve. My question should be: How can I have jars open in Java, and zips open in Engrampa?

I can have both zips and jars opened by either Java or Engrampa. There are others, but I'm only really interested in those two.
When I go to a jar and tell it to open with Java every time, then go and try to open a zip, it does nothing. When I check what it's trying to open it with, and I find that it's trying to open it with Java.
Then I switch the zip to open with Engrampa, and it opens, but later, I try opening a jar, and it opens in Engrampa.

I'm using Oracle JDK 8u121, installed from Oracle's zip(not the PPA), on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 64-bit.

Comment: I installed Oracle Java 8 with the PPA and it works fine, jar files are opened with Oracle Java 8 runtime. Perhaps it wasn't correctly installed.

Comment: Maybe. There's probably something the PPA installer does that I didn't. I can run jars, it's just that I can't make my system open zips with one and jars with the other.

Comment: So, when you change the default software for jar it gets changed for zip too? That's more a problem with MATE's file manager than anything else.